# Reverse a given number

Tags: c, loops, integer, printf, reverse

How to handle the test case if I enter the number 10000
and I get 1 as a result instead of getting 00001.
How to handle this case?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
      int n, rev = 0, remainder;
      printf("Enter an integer: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      while (n != 0) {
         remainder = n % 10;
         rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
         n /= 10;
     }
     printf("Reversed number = %d", rev);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is not 00001 the same as 1 is it?

Comment: You're reading a string from standard input... why don't you just reverse and print that instead?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but I want in the format of 00001. No. of digits should remain the same in given number

Comment: @Segmentationfault then see my answer.

Comment: Numeric data types ('int', 'float', etc) are for numeric *values* not *numbers*. There is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the number of digits in your number, and then print the number with a formatted length:

```
int numDigits = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    ...
    numDigits++;
}
```

and then:

```
printf("Reversed number = %.*d", numDigits, rev);
```

Comment: Could you suggest how can I do if the same thing I want to in c++?

Comment: @Segmentationfault This code should work in C++ as well of course, but more "C++-like" code would be: `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(numDigits) << rev << std::endl`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%n` specifier to count the number of digits entered. Note the space before the first `%n` to skip any whitespace. Also this will fail if the input is not an integer in range.
Then use the number of digits to pad the output `%0*d` with leading zeros.

Try with input of `10000` and `00001`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void) {
    int n, rev = 0, remainder;
    int start = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    printf ( "Enter an integer: ");
    scanf ( " %n%d%n", &start, &n, &stop);
    int digits = stop - start;
    while ( n != 0 || digits) {
        --digits;
        remainder = n % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf ( "Reversed number = %0*d", stop - start, rev);
    return 0;
}
```

outout:

```
Enter an integer: 00002
Reversed number = 20000
Enter an integer: 3000
Reversed number = 0003
```

Comment: `%n` is underappreciated :) it's worth nothing that misuse of `%n` can pose security risks (and it is disabled by default in Microsoft compilers).

Answer (score -1):

In general the reversed number can not fit in an object of its type.

It is better to use the type `unsigned int` instead of the type `int`. Otherwise you can get an unexpected result.

What you need is just to output the reversed number in a field with the width equal to the number of digits in the entered number prefixed with zeroes if required.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    
    unsigned int n = 0;
      
    printf( "Enter an integer: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );
      
    unsigned int rev = 0;
    int count = 0;
      
    do
    {
        rev = rev * Base + n % Base;
        ++count;
    } while ( n /= Base );
    
    printf( "Reversed number = %0*u", count, rev );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter an integer: 10000
Reversed number = 00001
```

Comment: Why would signed vs unsigned int matter?

Comment: @shrewmouse Because an overflow of a signed integer results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Then how would you handle the input of a negative number?

Comment: @shrewmouse The program deals with unsigned integers.

Comment: There is no such stipulation to only handle unsigned integers.

Comment: @shrewmouse Otherwise the program will be more complicated. No answer here provided a correct solution for signed integers though they use signed integers. So my approach is the most correct among others